# What are the two 'sides' of a decimal number called?

Tags: terminology, decimal-expansion

Is there a fancy name for the "left side" and "right side" of a decimal number?

(That is, the pre-decimal part and the post-decimal part.)

Comment: The integral part and the fractional part?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We really do use "[integer part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_part)" and "[fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)" respectively: see Wikipedia, e.g., on [decimal fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_number#Decimal_fractions).

> The integer part, or integral part of a decimal number is the part to the left of the **decimal separator**. (See also truncation.) The part from the decimal separator to the right is the fractional part.

Comment: Ahh yes perfect.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Will accept at some point.

Comment: I thought your question was fine. Some use "radix" to designate the decimal separator. A decimal fraction refers to a fraction whose denominator is a power of ten.

Comment: Just to clarify, `radix` is the actual dot?  Learning all sorts of new words today, cheers.

Comment: Yes...radix would be the "dot"! ;-)

Comment: Yes it's  perfect !

Comment: Confirmed this years later with some dev docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=netframework-4.8 They refer to "integral" and "fractional".

Comment: @Ben "Just to clarify, radix is the actual dot?" The radix is the base of the number system. Calling the dot a "radix" is just wrong. Calling it the "radix point" is correct (it's not a dot in all language locales).

Answer (score 16):

In normal use, "integer part" and "fractional part" does reign supreme.

However if the decimal is used in the context of [logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm), the terms you want are "characteristic" and "mantissa".  A generation ago, when sliderules were common, these terms were better known.

Comment: *whistle* That's the sort of fancypants thing I was expecting, something that's fun to say, like "Mantissa".  I think I may bow to the supreme non-slideruler, though.

Comment: By the way, I assume the `characteristic` is the `integer` part?

Comment: @Steve, that's right; follow the link I gave for more details.

Comment: In computer science floating-point numbers have the sign, the exponent, and the mantissa.

Answer (score -1):

The left side of the decimal is called whole number and the right side of the decimal is known as decimal.